# issue with content center larger than it should css/html

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, center

I've noticed a new issue that was working without any problem before and I don't understand what is going on and how to fix it.

Here is the problem. I'm used to center div in my website this way:

```
<div id="banner">
     <div class="center">conter here is centered</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#banner
{
  width:100%
}

.center
{
  width:900px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

The div is correctly centered. The issue is, when I resize the webbrowser (chrome, opera, firefox) to 916px; a horizontal scrollbar appears when it should actually appear at 900px.

It worked before without any probleme and stopped now. Why?

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any padding applied to `#banner` ?

Answer (score 3):

Please **reset** the default margin and padding from your page.

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Using a `reset.css` with a good reset will reset all the browser differences in CSS. I would recommend [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)'s reset for most and [HTML5 Doctor Reset](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) for HTML 5.

Also it is not a good reason always to have `width` and `padding` or `margin` or `border` together. If you are using them in conjunction, please also add this:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Can someone explain the reason for downvote? I am happy to correct or improve the answer.

Comment: It is a duplicate of what I already posted, with near-identical formatting?

Comment: @Jason Well, kinda. `:)` Accept it. Lemme add more info then?

Comment: If it adds to the question, yes. I will remove the downvote then.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove the default `margin` and `padding` from your page?

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

In Chrome the `body` tag has `padding: 8px` applied to it. This might result in it breaking at 916px?

Often a **css reset** of all default styles is applied to a document beforehand to eliminate such issues from creeping up. [Here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is some more info on the subject of resetting CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

I did not mention it but of course I tried with a css reset. I also tried to reset every margin/padding on the HTML and BODY but it doesn't solve the problem.

What I really do not understand is that it was working few months ago, I'm 1000% sure about that. so What changed recently?

I create an exemple (which is not really revelant since you cannot resize the browser on JSfiddle but please try it on your side):

```
(https://jsfiddle.net/2gjt4v3e/)
```

I added a lot of 'br' because I noticed that the issue appears when the website has a certain height. If you do the test with 2 lines for example it works, if you do it again with more content (and so a bigger height) the issue appears.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I forgot about this post.

I always set a reset, that is not the issue of the marging / padding.

Regards,

Comment: from review: Is this a comment or an information ? for sure not an answer. Please check